# Text alignment not working as expected in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, text, fabricjs

My project requires being able to insert text on a Canvas, with the user able to specify whether it should be flush left, flush right, or centered in the specified bounding box. I'm using fabric.js and setting the value of textAlign, but it doesn't work as I expected. The x position which I specify is always the left edge of the text. If I set textAlign to "center" and have multiple lines of text, they are indeed centered with respect to one another, but they aren't centered in the bounding box; rather, the X position I specified is always the left edge of the longest line.

The code which sets up the element is as follows:

```
var text = new fabric.Text(this.getText(), {
   hasControls: false,
   selectable: false,
   fontSize: this.getPointSize(),
   fontFamily: this.getTypeface(),
   fill: this.getColor(),
   left: xpos,
   top: pos.y,
   originX: pos.originx,
   originY: pos.originy,
   width: this.getWidth(),
   height: this.getHeight(),
   fontWeight: weight,
   fontStyle: fstyle,
   textAlign: alignment
});
```

What I want is to draw right-aligned text whose right edge is a specified X position, or centered text that is centered on the midpoint between a specified left and right edge. Is there a way to do this using Fabric and/or Canvas?

Comment: You could add an additional function for when the alignment changes.  If the alignment is set to right, adjust the x position of the element by the width of the text object.  If alignment is centered, then use 1/2 of the width.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that what you want is `fabric.Textbox`, isn't it?

The feature `fabric.Textbox` has **not been released yet**, but there is a pull request on github.
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/1778

Waiting for new release will be better, but, if you need this feature as soon as possible, you would be able to use it from a branch which makes the pull request.
https://github.com/PosterMyWall/fabric.js/tree/TextboxPullRequest

Comment: That definitely looks worth trying. Wrapping would be a wonderful thing for my application too.